# Adding space between text and image in Markdown

Tags: image, markdown, kramdown

In Markdown, you add an image as

```
![myimg](link)
```

Now, I can easily change the size and placement of said image using attributes as

```
![myimg](link){: height="75px" width="300px" align="left"}
```

How do I also make it so that there is also a (choosable) space between image and text? Parameters like `border` don't work.

Using Kramdown as converter, on Github pages, if that matters.

Comment: @StevenPenny Yea tried that as well to no avail!

Comment: use CSS... (markdown/html is not for layouting)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Markdown is not capable of designing layouts like this. You can use **multiple non-breaking spaces** (`&nbsp;`) to adjust the spacing between an image and text.

**Example:**

```
![image](link)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;text
```

**Result:**

[image]    text

Answer (score 3):

For this to work for me for the paragraph of text next to the image, I used this:

```
![myimg](link){: height="75px" width="300px" style="float:left; padding-right:10px" }
```