# How to use margin/padding in GitHub README.md?

Tags: html, css, github, r-markdown, readme

#### Issue

I'm trying to display several images in GitHub's README.md with a margin of `x` px between them. But for some reason GitHub seems to strip away the `margin-right: 30px` style.

#### Markdown

```
[<img style="margin-right: 30px" src=foo.svg height=30>](https://www.example.com/)
[<img style="margin-right: 30px" src=bar.svg height=30>](https://www.example.com/)
<!-- ...and so on -->
```

**Note:** I tried `align="left"` [here](https://github.com/vinaysharma14#technologies--tools-%EF%B8%8F) which works fine but breaks on `lg` `sm` `xs` devices.

Comment: Similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046263/how-to-indent-a-few-lines-in-markdown-markup/

Answer (score 5):

> #### It is not possible to use different types of `styles` in GitHub markdown.

*Github only allows to use of some attributes inside the HTML tag and also removes some attributes from the tag if the user puts them inside the HTML tag.*

Also, we cannot use CSS in GitHub markdown because it is part of the sanitization process.

> The HTML is sanitized, aggressively removing things that could harm you and your kin—such as `<script>` tags, inline styles, and `class` or `id` attributes.

*source: https://github.com/github/markup#github-markup*

If we use an HTML block in the markdown file something like

```html
<div style="margin-right: 30px;">

Markdown content goes here.

</div>
```

Then, When GitHub rendered it, the style attribute was automatically removed and no CSS style was applied. It will render it something like

```html
<div>

Markdown content goes here.

</div>
```

> N.B: In the case of positioning, the align attribute is the only way that will currently work. Despite being deprecated, it's still rendered.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `&nbsp;` to make space instead of CSS margin.

Comment: Impractical for 10s and 100s of pixels of margin.

Comment: @Vinay Sharma, you could also try other whitespace characters available in HTML (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode), such as `&ensp;`, `&emsp;`, `&thinsp;` or `&hairsp;`.

Comment: Still, do you really think using other characters would be efficient? I don't see a reason why would someone like to end up with 100s of such characters.`&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;...100times`

Comment: Why would you need such huge spaces in a markdown file? %)
Use `align` property on the HTML element if you want to push something to the right (GH .md supports it). Otherwise a bunch of `&emsp;`s is fine, I haven't found a better solution :)

Answer (score 3):

## At last, you can do it hacky way ✨

While a bit hacky, you can use `<dl>`, `<dt>` and `<dd>` tags in combination to make indent without any enumeration (unlike `<ul>`/`+`/`-`/`*` or `<ol>`/`1. 2. 3.`).

<sub>The lines in preview below are generated by `---`, but it works without those.</sub>

See example below:

```
This is normal text.

---

<dl>
  <dd>This gets indented, without enumeration nor dots.</dd>
</dl>

---

<dl>
  <dd>
    <dl>
      <dd>
        Multiple levels seems to be possible?
      </dd>
    </dl>
  </dd>
</dl>

---

<dl><dd><dl><dd><dl><dd><dl><dd>
Yes, but syntax gets messy, unless you write it single line :)
</dd></dl></dd></dl></dd></dl></dd></dl>
```

Result preview:
[image: Result preview]

[Check it directly in my GitHub gist here.](https://gist.github.com/AgainPsychoX/cd2817c008537acb3b0efc954e773fd8)

Comment: Thank you, this should be accepted answer. Also check GitHub's markdown compiler (filter): https://github.com/gjtorikian/html-pipeline/blob/main/lib/html/pipeline/sanitization_filter.rb

Answer (score 1):

Well I have been seeking the answer and I found some links that can help but not kinda solve it all.

**1---This is for Horizontal Spacing:**

```
![image](link)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;text
```

[Link to the Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48667554/22393472)

**2---This Put a rounded nice border around your image:**
Just use kbd tag around your image tag. [My Github Profile](https://github.com/Mina-Nadifi)

```
<kbd></kbd>
```

Still seeking for more intel of having margins on Github profile using Github Markdown in Readme.md file.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add

```
<div align="center">
<div align="center">
<div align="center">
<p>a</p>
</div>
<p>a</p>
<p>b</p>
</div>
<p>a</p>
<p>b</p>
<p>c</p>
</div>
```

By adding a div you can customize the position
You refer the outcome in my [GitHub](https://github.com/vishnudas-bluefox)
[image: The result looks like]

Answer (score 0):

## Hack Required

Due to GitHub's HTML sanitization (removing a lot of the attributes and values), you'll need to find an unorthodox way of styling your page. One way I found pretty effective was to create an invisible image, completely transparent, and include that between the images you want margin.

#### Example

```
<div align="center">
  <span><img src="./loginScreen.jpg" height=650 width=300 /></span>
  <span><img src="./aligner.png" height=50 width=150 /></span> <!--invisible-->
  <span><img src="./Expenses.jpg" height=650 width=300 /></span>
</div>
```

You can easily alter the height and width of that image as if it were the top/bottom, left/right margin. Hope that helps!