# How to center image with Markdown?

Tags: r-markdown, markdown

I have tried to center an image and I have not been able, I have found that you can center text,  Centered text , but I have not found examples of how to center an image, thanks in advance to those who know

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41514579/3151675

Answer (score 4):

In your chunk options.

```
{r chunkName, fig.align="center", out.height="90%", out.width = "90%", fig.cap=" Whatever.\\label{whatever}"}

knitr::include_graphics("figures/whatever.png")
```

Comment: """![ghost](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/30079428/123889885-b85fb300-d92c-11eb-93df-07a974e21eb2.gif)"""
I am customizing my Github with this gift, this is the line that inserts the gift, your help did not work for me, thank you very much

Comment: I suggest you provide more information about your problem and some code in order to have more specifications.

Answer (score 0):

for those rendering to docs...
I accomplished this by having a well-formatted docx template and then specifying that section in my code... In my case heading 3 (###) is centered in my word doc template.

```
---
output:
  word_document:
    reference_docx: template.docx
---
```

...your other code...

```
### ![](image.png){width=250}
```